# Xamarin Essentials VS Google Maps API

Tags: xamarin, google-maps-api-3

What is the difference between using these two methods when trying to find city and state from the zip code a user enters. When using Essentials as far as I can tell you have to make two calls, one to get the longitude/latitude of zip code and then another to get more information from the longitude/latitude.

```
public async Task GetLocationEssentials(string zip)
{
    var locations = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(zip);
    var location = locations?.FirstOrDefault();
    if (location != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
    }

    try
    {
        var lat = location.Latitude;
        var lon = location.Longitude;

        var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(lat, lon);

        var placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();
        if (placemark != null)
        {
            var geocodeAddress =
                $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
                $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
                $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
                $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
                $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
                $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
                $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
                $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
                $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
                $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

            Console.WriteLine(geocodeAddress);
        }
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
    {
        // Feature not supported on device
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception that may have occurred in geocoding
    }
}
```

The second option is obtaining a google maps API key and making a call to their api using the zip code but this requires obtaining a api key and then your limited to 2500 calls per day.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GetLocationAsync(string zip)
{
    string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zip + "&sensor=true";
    var client = new HttpClient();

    // 'using' forces proper cleanup after finishing the operation
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(jsonResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a benefit to using the googleapi call other than only having to make 1 call? Will the essentials lock you out if you make to many calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core difference is Essentials is using the "native" features of each platform for Geolocation services so your results will vary from platform to platform for the same address/LatLong location.

On iOS, `CLGeocoder` is used and thus Apple's geo-location database is used, like wise Android uses `Geocoder` (the results are much simpler & sparse when compared the Googles API) and UWP uses `BasicGeoposition` (A map token is required).

Google direct Geolocation APIs provide a consistent request set across platforms and (BEWARE: opinion-based) a much fuller result set.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. I just figured the native geocoders would be using the google api somewhere in their code. Thank you!